# Automate deployment and configuration of pfsense on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, pfsense

How would you go about automating deployment and configuration of a HA pfsense cluster in AWS?

I have looked in to ansible playbooks  ans AWS Systems Manager for doing this but there is not much information on this topic. pfsense also has an API that could be used for automating configuration once deployed. Possibly a boostrap script to copy config from S3 would be another approach to automate configuration once deployed.

What is the best practice for doing something like this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with pfsense that can't be solved with existing AWS tools and services (like WAF and security groups)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. One of the main reasons is to use a firewall that uses snort for IPS/IDS. I'm aware of WAF and Shield as well can get a similar result.